# Mesos slave statistics

Tags: scheduler, mesos

In Mesos do the slaves report only CPU, and Memory information to the master? Can they propogate any other custom information. For example I have an application that can tell how busy it is to an external process. Can it report that information to the Mesos slave which inturn reports to the Master and get used in resource offers?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I can think of a few ways to get your custom information from slaves to the framework. Maybe one of these would work for you.

1. You can use the --resources and --attributes flags to add custom resources/attributes that may allow you to specify some of these stats/values at slave-start-time, which would then be included in resource offers.
2. Or you could have a custom executor for your framework that passes such information in the 'data' field of its statusUpdates.
3. Or maybe you could add a custom isolator (like with 0.21's new isolator modules), then have it report different metrics on the slave's /stats.json endpoint.

Comment: Hey Adam, I think (2) would be an overkill to collect metrics unless that is the main goal of the application I think but this could be a nice addition to Marathon :)
On the other hand I don't see how this can be achieved by (1), can you elaborate?